# merge two versions of files (two-way merge)

Tags: file, unix, merge, filesystems

I have two different versions of a file (one has bug fixes, the other is slightly updated) which I would like to merge together.  In particular I would like to keep the common material, and incorporate parts of the changes from each version --- i.e. I want a two-way merge, instead of the standard `merge [options] file1 file file2` command.

Is there a way to do this outside of version control?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [vimdiff](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/diff.txt.html), if you like vim, or something like [Meld](http://meldmerge.org/), if you like graphical interfaces. Here's a screenshot for the latter:

[image: meld screenshot]